# How to dynamically add a linear layout (as a child) to a constraint layout (parent)?

Tags: java, android

I defined a method to create a linear layout and to add it to parent layout. But it didn't work. I think I made mistake(s).

```
    public void methodName() {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        ConstraintLayout main = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        main.addView(linearLayout);
   }
```

Comment: Are u getting any exception?

Comment: I didn't see, but I didn't see red color. It looks like no linear layout at all!

Comment: Please post the content of mainLayout.xml

Comment: Almost no content, just a floating button.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't post it as a comment because it is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add views to a ConstraintLayout you have to add the constraints using a ConstraintSet.

While Adding dynamic views to constraint layout, it is a bit different from other layouts.  You need to specify the constraints as well like this below:-

```
     ConstraintLayout main = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
     ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

     LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
     linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
     linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
     linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
     main.addView(linearLayout,0);
     set.clone(main);
     set.connect(linearLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, main.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 60);
     set.applyTo(main);
```

Comment: Thank you. You solved my problem. I just replaced "layout" by "main" and adjusted the margin.